# track the number of recipients who received the mail which was sent to bulk email ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, radio-button

i have made a mailer and used smtp to send emails in which there are three radiobox buttons to select the data source which contains the list of receivers to whom emails would be sent. Here is the code-

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                SendHTMLMail();

            }


now, suppose there are around say 500/1000 recipients of my mail, then how can i find the number of recipients to who my mail was successfully delivered 

            void SendHTMLMail()
            {  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/index1.html"));
            string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            string myString ;
            myString = readFile;

                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();  

                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text);


                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text; 
                Msg.Body = mystring.ToString();
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                if (fuAttachment.HasFile)          
                {
                    string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);

                    Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));    
                }
                if (RadioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    sql.Open();
                    string s = "select * from address";
                    SqlCommand t = new SqlCommand(s, sql);
                    t.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sql.Close();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM address1";
                    cmd.Connection = sql;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    sql.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    sql.Close();

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {

                        Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
                    }


                }
                else if (RadioButton2.Checked)
                {
                    string connectionString = "";
                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                        {

                            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }    
                        else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                        {
                            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                        }
                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        con.Open();
                        DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                        string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT address FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        dAdapter.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();


                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {

                            Msg.To.Add(row["address"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (RadioButton3.Checked)
                {
                    if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
                    {
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);

                        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
                        FileUpload2.SaveAs(fileLocation);
                        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation);
                        String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        string[] toAddressArray;
                        toAddressArray = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
                        foreach (string a in toAddressArray)
                        {
                            Msg.To.Add(a);

                        }
                    }
                }

                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; 
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtpwd.Text);
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(Msg);   
                    Msg = null;
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);


                }

            }
```

now, suppose there are 500/1000 recipients of my mail, then how can i find the number of recipients who successfully received my mail. By this, i mean that suppose i want to send a mail to 500 people and while sending, it stops after say 231th receiver. So is there a way to track it?

Comment: This cannot be done easily. If you really want this I suggest you use a service for sending newsletters. They have that stuff build-in.

Comment: FYI: Your code is all about sending email. Seeing how it is read is a totally different issue. While I am at it: Radio buttons (your tag radio-button) has nothing to do with email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Track if the email is read by the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145347/track-if-the-email-is-read-by-the-client)

Comment: by this, i mean that suppose i want to send a mail to 500 people and while sending, it stops after say 231th reciever. So is there a way to track it?

Answer (score 1):

Your SmtpMail.Send(message) will return an error if the message is not successfuly sent. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx) to see the explanation and an simple example.

So I think that you can check if any exception is thrown by it and if not, then you can count it as an "Email Sent Successfuly".

```
// Request both failure and success report
Msg.DeliveryNotification = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | 
DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess; 

int emailsSent = 0;

try 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("start to send email ..."); 
     smtp.Send(Msg); 
     emailsSent++;
     Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");

} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:"); 
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
}
```

Comment: can you provide the lines of code that will count the number of SmtpFailedRecipientsException

Comment: @harsha is that enough?

Comment: is there any way to know the number say 212 after which the mail wasn't sent or the total number of recipients who got the mail out of say 500?

Comment: @harsha I added "emailsSent" now. You can use it to identify the number of successfuly emails sent like I'm doing in this example :)

Comment: its throwing the error- Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for the line-  Msg.DeliveryNotification = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | 
DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;

Comment: @harsha I noticed now that you are sending **one** email to a lot of addresses. I think that to know what you're trying to you must send an email per address and do something like I did. You can parallelize it and use the _SendAsync_ method to optimize it.

Comment: Is your _Msg_ variable initialized?

Comment: but i require to send the same email to minimum 500 recipients and i can't do it sending one by one as it will be too time consuming

Comment: the Msg variable is instantiated -   MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

Comment: In that case I believe that you cannot control the status (sent or failed) for each individual address @harsha.

Comment: so there in no way to track it?

Comment: I believe that to achieve what you intend to you must do like I said. One _Send_ call per address.

Comment: What do you mean with "bulk email sending"? Do you know any Send overload in SmtpClient to do that?